# Open a .pem file in Android to get Public RSA key

Tags: android, rsa

So I did not find a good answer focused on Android for that issue.

Starting for the beginning, I got a `.pem` file from a trusted server to be used in `RSA encryption` , so I guess the first question would be where to put this `.pem` file within the Android project?? `raw` folder maybe?

Second question will be basically how to load/read this `.pem` file and extract the Public key out of it?.

Comment: Any number of different things may be stored in `.pem` files. You need to figure out what is inside. The `-----BEGIN` line should tell you.

Comment: I think it is the actual Public Key stored in the `.pem`, if I open it with TextEdit I can see a long string starting with `MIGfMA....`. which has the same structure as a Public Key I have seen before, is that possible?...there is nothing like `----BEGIN....`

Comment: You need to figure out what's inside. Ask whoever gave it to you.

Comment: it is the actual Public key

Comment: In what format?

Comment: Base64 encoded I think

Comment: Did you find a place where to keep the pem file?